# Condicionales relacionadas

Tags: c#, asp.net

Traigo datos desde mi base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es traer todos esos datos a mi html, el problema es que para los que tengan "1" en el campo *nivel* se cree una etiqueta ***li*** , eso lo hago con este pedazo de codigo:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
if(nivel=="1")
{
//el 'tree2' es el id de una etiqueta <ul> en el html, que esta con un runat="server"

 tree2.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

El problema es en la siguiente condición, para los registros que tengan "2" en el campo *nivel* se cree la etiqueta ***ul*** dentro de la etiqueta ***li*** que cree en la primera condición. Lo intento hacer con este mismo codigo:

```
if(nivel=="2")
{    
 HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
 li.Controls.Add(ul);
}
```

Cuando hago esto, los registros con el valor "2" en el campo *nivel* no sale, a menos que en vez de poner ***li.Controls.Add(ul)*** ponga ***tree2.Controls.Add(ul)***

Necesito una manera de decir, para los que tienen *nivel = "1"* que se haga esto, y para los que tengan *nivel="2"* que se haga esto dentro de lo que se hizo para la primera condición.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los que están en el nivel agregan el control UL al LI, pero nunca agregas el LI al tree2.  Modificando el primer if debería funcionar:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
if(nivel=="1" || nivel=="2")
{
    tree2.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

¡Suerte!